# Reading chunks of data from file (C)

Tags: c, file, buffer

My binary file contains chunks of data in the following format:

**0xAA ... variable length of bytes ...  0XFF**

Is there a good way to read these chunks of data directly into a buffer, instead of reading the file one byte at a time?

Comment: Have a look at `fread`.

Comment: Circular buffer as you do not know message length.

Comment: Is there a good way to achieve this circular buffering?

Comment: You might have to read in 2 chunks with a circular buffer. I don't see the relevance for block reads.

Comment: maybe not 2 chunks but when you read a fixed length chunk of data it may contain the full message or not. So the buffer manipulation is the only "dificult" part of this program.

Comment: That is exactly my point, as some chunks have 32 bytes, while others exceed 256MB.

Answer (score -2):

You Can use "fopen" to open the file "rb" stands for read binary,

```
 FILE* fileptr;
    unsigned char* buffer;
    fileptr = fopen("file_name", "rb");  // r for read, b for binary

        fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END); // fseek will take fileptr to end of file (SEEK_END)

        filelen = ftell(fileptr); //here we get filelen
        printf("file len =%d\n", filelen);
        rewind(fileptr);

        buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(filelen * sizeof(unsigned char));
        fread(buffer, filelen, 1, fileptr);
        fclose(fileptr);
```

finally you will get all your binary file content in buffer pointer.

Don't forget to free buffer after use.

Comment: I don't want to read the whole file in a buffer. I need to read the chunks sequentially.

Comment: one byte at a time of multiple byte at a time??

Comment: int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
you can see the use of fseek function here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html
Basically you can give apprpriate offset and depending on that you will get filelen and you can read that much chunk of data